# header dont move with horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

Can anyone please suggest me the solution.

The Header is not moving with the table when I scroll horizontal.
The header comes outside the div.

I am referencing the following [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/hvRZy/)

Comment: But why should it move with the table? It's outside the table. Why don't you just put a horizontal scrollbar on the body instead of on the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your property `overflow: auto;` on `#topsection` and remove on `#table-container`, it works.

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hvRZy/1/)</kbd>

```
#topsection {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
#table-container {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete 
`overflow: auto;`

Line 54 in your css code